# Why i can't talk my project google assistant on my phone

Tags: actions-on-google

I use xiaomi redmi 3S with android version 6. I can't talk with my project google assistant on my phone. dev or production.Please your information...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open simulator page on your browser(phone)?

Or you may try to open the link that you can get by clicking share button on simulator page.

After that, you should be able to open by say "OK Google, talk to my test app(or your invocation name)" and see on Google Assistant(App) - Explore.

Comment: Yes I have tried it in the simulator and it works well. And i tried on my friend's cellphone with OS Android 9 it could work well.

Comment: Do you use your mail which you used for development on your phone?